# Adding a custom VS Code setting for a file type (.pug)

Tags: javascript, pug, visual-studio-code

How can I set a VS code setting active only an a certain file extension?

In my case it's
`"editor.renderWhitespace": "boundary"` on all `.pug` and `.jade` files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your settings within an object that has the keyword `[jade]` ([Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35350#issuecomment-333067226)):

```
{
    "[jade]": {
        "editor.renderWhitespace": "boundary",
    }
}
```

The above will support both **jade** and **pug** files, you don't need to define it for both.